# Angular2 Project to Plunker

Tags: angular, plunker

How do I get my Angular2 project running in Plunker that I can give other people examples of some functionalities without recreating every single file and resource?

Comment: if you are using angular CLI than use https://stackblitz.com  for sharing your angular project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use core http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview with all @angular libraries, 
adjust systemjs.config file to add your special libs.
It uses latest RC5 but you can use any.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Add your special files and you are done.

Comment: I got the impression there is a way to get a Plunker from a Github repo or similar but haven't found details. Do you know about such a way?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible... where did you get this idea?

Comment: I think I saw this mentioned somewhere. It's a while ago. I kept looking for hints, but have seen any. It also seems the Angular team is generating them somehow from their examples in the GitHub repo but I don't know how.

Comment: I think it is good idea to keep plunker's examples small and clear, that tremendously helps to understand code (for those who reads  and for author also).

Comment: Sure but GitHub repos don't need to be big ;-) and it would make it easy to try them locally as well.

Comment: I can't see why it would not be possible. Just set up systemjs mapping to point to rawgithubuser.com, which would proxy rawcontents. Maybe proxy is not even needed.

Comment: Ok I thought there would be an easier way of doing it. But with the simplicity thing you are right.